# Transforming onclick into onchange

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, onclick, onchange

for last few days I've been creating contact form for my website which might be professional and contain display:none/block and disabled:true/false areas. And I made it. But an hour ago I was informed that Chrome doesn't support "onclick" function so now I must change this all "onlick" stuff into "onchange".. but it doesn't seem clearly (still not working)...

ONCLICK works fine:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function enableField() { some function here }
    function disableField() { some function here }
</script>

<select class="list" id="topic">
    <option onclick="javascript:disableField()" selected="selected">Select Your topic</option>
    <option onclick="javascript:enableField()">Topic 1</option>
    <option onclick="javascript:enableField()">Topic 2</option>
    <option onclick="javascript:disableField()">Topic 3</option>
    <option onclick="javascript:disableField()">Topic 4</option>
</select>
```

ONCHANGE does NOT:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function enableField() { some function here }
    function disableField() { some function here }
</script>

<select class="list" id="topic" onchange="javascript:this.value()">
    <option value="disableField" selected="selected">Select Your topic</option>
    <option value="enableField">Topic 1</option>
    <option value="enableField">Topic 3</option>
    <option value="disableField">Topic 3</option>
    <option value="disableField">Topic 4</option>
</select>
```

I just wanted to be "value" inserted as "X" in "javascript:X()" so this functions can work in way as it happened in "ONLICK" option.

I've been trying maaaany different ways but none of this works.

Please help.
Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it

```
<select class="list" id="topic" onchange="window[this.value]()">
    <option value="disableField" selected="selected">Select Your topic</option>
    <option value="enableField">Topic 1</option>
    <option value="enableField">Topic 3</option>
    <option value="disableField">Topic 3</option>
    <option value="disableField">Topic 4</option>
</select>
```

---

But i would do it like this

```
<script language="javascript">
    function enableField() { some function here }
    function disableField() { some function here }
    function handle(value){
       if (value === 'enableField'){
           enableField();
       } else {
           disableField();
       }
    }
</script>

<select class="list" id="topic" onchange="handle(this.value)">
    <option value="disableField" selected="selected">Select Your topic</option>
    <option value="enableField">Topic 1</option>
    <option value="enableField">Topic 3</option>
    <option value="disableField">Topic 3</option>
    <option value="disableField">Topic 4</option>
</select>
```

---

***Note:** for event attributes like `onclick`, `onchange` etc, you do not have to say `javascript:...` it is implied..*

Comment: Gaby, thank You a lot!! I will choose the second way, seems clearly and understood. THANKS!! :))))

Answer (score 0):

```
this.value()
```

is a string; you can't call a string. What you want is to find the function in the global scope:

```
window[this.value]()
```

Also, it's better to store the functions in a dedicated object:

```
funcs = {
  disableField: function(){...},
  enableField: function(){...},
}

...

funcs[this.value]()
```